# mongodb $geowithin for multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection with geojson points. I have another collection with geojson `multipolygons`. How can I run `$geowithin` against all the boundaries in another collection?. Since the data is very large, loading all the boundaries in memory is very time consuming and memory consuming ( sometimes failing ) process. what can be a good approach here? I have not seen any example where boundary ( multipolygon ) field is dynamic ( comming from all rows of db ) in case of $geowithin

Comment: There are no such examples because $geometry parameter is passed to mongodb by value. The only way you can dynamically build it is on application level. Out of curiosity how large the polygon is? I mean how many coordinates are there?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AlexBlex. I have around 50000 boundaries. Each boundary is a multipolygon indicating a World City ( e.g London ) at different admin levels ( admin level 2, 3, 4... etc ). Due to different admin levels the number is huge. 1 polygon can contain upto 10000 coordinate points on average

Comment: yeah, that's a lot. Assuming a point weights 16 bytes, 1 polygon will be up to 160 Kb, which mill totalling to 8 Gb for all boundaries. Are you saying you managed to query $geowithin with 8Gb points in the payload? I am surprised it is working at all.

Comment: yes. it is working and it is consuming around 6gb of ram. I had to run node with `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`